# How to transpose a javascript object into a key/value array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given a JavaScript object, how can I convert it into an array of objects (each with key, value)?

Example:

```
var data = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'john.doe@gmail.com' }
```

resulting like:

```
[
  { key: 'firstName', value: 'John' },
  { key: 'lastName', value: 'Doe' },
  { key: 'email', value: 'john.doe@gmail.com' }
]
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```js
var data = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'john.doe@gmail.com' }
var output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({key,value}));

console.log(output);
```

Inspired By this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628432/how-to-convert-an-object-to-array-of-objects#)

Comment: Great answer. It's worth noting that the REVERSE can also be done, i.e. key-value to objects:  Object.fromEntries(data.map(({key,value})=>([key, value])));

Answer (score 24):

Using `map` function

```js
var data = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'john.doe@gmail.com' };

var result = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ key, value: data[key] }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is it an ECMAScript 6 solution?

Comment: @AlexanderPopov yes, it's `arrow` function

Comment: or change the variable name to key in the map and user the object property shorthand `key => ({ key, value: data[key] }) `

Answer (score 10):

You can just iterate over the object's properties and create a new object for each of them.

```
var data = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'john.doe@gmail.com' };
var result = [];

for(var key in data)
{
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        result.push({
            key: key,
            value: data[key]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: up for `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: up for `hasOwnProperty` but down for not doing it in a functional way, like @isvforall

Comment: @EmilOberg not doing it in a `ES6` way does not mean this is a not reliable (even great and far more readable) answer. A downvote seems odd.

Comment: @roko-c-buljan, there's nothing ES6 about it. `Object.keys` and `Array.map` is all good old EcmaScript 5.1. (Yes the arrow function @isvforall used is ES6 but not really an interesting part of the answer, e.g see the answer by @rob-brander)

Comment: @EmilOberg—"*there is nothing ES6 about it*" — except for the ES6 bits (arrow function, shorthand properties). :-/

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer lead me to think there is a better way...

```
Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  return { key, value: data[key] };
});
```

or in ES6 using arrow functions:

```
Object.keys(data).map((key) => ({ key, value: data[key] }));
```

Comment: Error: `Unexpected token :`

Comment: Ah, good catch; I've fixed it.  I was just missing the brackets around the arrow function return value.

Answer (score 5):

Just make your life easier and use es6 syntax with a map

```
    var output = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
      return {
        key: key,
        value: data[key]
      };
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = [];
for(var k in data) result.push({key:k,value:data[k]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or go wild and make the `key` and `value` keys customizable:

```
module.exports = function objectToKeyValueArray(obj, keyName = 'key', valueName = 'value') {
    return Object
        .keys(obj)
        .filter(key => Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
        .map(key => {
            const keyValue = {};
            keyValue[keyName] = key;
            keyValue[valueName] = obj[key];

            return keyValue;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method for doing this that works on multi level objects and does not use recursion.

```
var output = []

    var o = {
      x:0,
      y:1,
      z:{
        x0:{
          x1:4,
          y1:5,
          z1:6
        },
        y0:2,
        z0:[0,1,2],
      }
    }

    var  defer = [ [ o ,[ '_root_' ] ] ]
    var _defer = []


    while(defer.length){

    var current = defer.pop()

    var root    = current[1]
        current = current[0]


      for(var key in current ){

        var path = root.slice()
            path.push(key)

        switch( current[key].toString() ){
        case '[object Object]':
          _defer.push( [ current[key] , path ] )
        break;;
        default:
         output.push({
          path  : path ,
          value : current[key]
         })
        break;;
        }
      }

      if(!defer.length)
          defer = _defer.splice(0,_defer.length)
    }

[
{ path: [ '_root_', 'x' ], value: 0 },
{ path: [ '_root_', 'y' ], value: 1 },
{ path: [ '_root_', 'z', 'y0' ], value: 2 },
{ path: [ '_root_', 'z', 'z0' ], value: [ 0, 1, 2 ] },
{ path: [ '_root_', 'z', 'x0', 'x1' ], value: 4 },
{ path: [ '_root_', 'z', 'x0', 'y1' ], value: 5 },
{ path: [ '_root_', 'z', 'x0', 'z1' ], value: 6 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
    { key: "key1", value: "value1" },
    { key: "key2", value: "value2" },
];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(array.map(item => [item.key, item.value]));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is the inverse way

Comment: This just saved me.

Answer (score -2):

I would say to use npm package flat. 
works amazing for nested objects and arrays.

```
var flatten = require('flat')

flatten({
    key1: {
        keyA: 'valueI'
    },
    key2: {
        keyB: 'valueII'
    },
    key3: { a: { b: { c: 2 } } }
})

// {
//   'key1.keyA': 'valueI',
//   'key2.keyB': 'valueII',
//   'key3.a.b.c': 2
// }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const array = [
    { key: "key1", value: "value1" },
    { key: "key2", value: "value2" },
];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(array.map(item => [item.key, item.value]));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.