# Define names for JS object properties

Tags: javascript

I have this object that looks like that

```
{taxi: 1, food: 1, cinema: 2, drinks: 2}
```

My goal is to define a name for those properties like so :

```
const expenseCategories = [
  { name: 'taxi', value: 1 },
  { name: 'food', value: 1 },
  { name: 'cinema', value: 2 },
  { name: 'drinks', value: 2},
];
```

Here is my attempt, I am nowhere near what I want to accomplish. I know it's simple but I got confused..

```
  var test = [];

  for (let x in expenseCategories) {
    // expenseCatAmountsObj.push(expenseCategories[x]);
    test.push( Object.defineProperty({}, {name : x}, { value: expenseCategories[x] }) )
  }
```

It just returns an array inside object

> [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: `test.push({ name: x, value: expenseCategories[x] })` or `var test = Object.keys(expenseCategories).map(key => { name: key, value: expenseCategories[key] });`

Comment: If you want to keep the code as it is, just use `Object.assign` instead of `defineProperty`. Otherwise, just push the item in a single shot as Chris suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an object to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628432/how-to-convert-an-object-to-array-of-objects) and [How to convert an object to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628432)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let obj = {taxi: 1, food: 1, cinema: 2, drinks: 2}

let out = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can loop over the keys of the object using map, which will return an array of results:

```js
let categories = {taxi: 1, food: 1, cinema: 2, drinks: 2};

let test = Object.keys(categories).map(k => {
    return { name: k, value: categories[k] }
});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const temp = {taxi: 1, food: 1, cinema: 2, drinks: 2};

let expenseCategories = Object.keys(temp).map(key => ({name: key, value: temp[key]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the steps almost right - only `Object.defineProperty({}, {name : x}, { value: expenseCategories[x] })` is unneeded, since it's overly complex way of doing what you want. Instead just use an object literal:

```js
var expenseCategories = { taxi: 1, food: 1, cinema: 2, drinks: 2 }

var test = [];

for (let x in expenseCategories) {
  test.push(
    {
      name: x,
      value: expenseCategories[x]
    }
  )
}

console.log(test)
```

An alternative is to iterate over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and produce an array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [short object initialisation syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
var expenseCategories = { taxi: 1, food: 1, cinema: 2, drinks: 2 }

var test = Object.entries(expenseCategories)
  .map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}))

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys`

```js
let obj = {taxi: 1, food: 1, cinema: 2, drinks: 2}
let arr = []

let keys = Object.keys(obj)

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i]
    arr[i] = {name: key, value: obj[key]}
}

console.log(arr)
```