# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' Angular 6

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive, angular6

I have a problem with. I looked for other solutions and found none that would help me.

The error is:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

My model.ts

```
export interface CEP {
    complemento: string;
    bairro: string;
    cidade: string;
    logradouro?: string;
    estado_info?: string[];
    cep: string;
    cidade_info?:string[]; 
    estado: string;
}
```

My service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CEP } from './cep/cep.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Injectable()
 export class CEPSerivce {

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

     ceps(numCEP: string): Observable<CEP[]> {
         return this.http.get<CEP[]> 
      (`https://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/${numCEP}`);
     }
   }
```

My model.ts

```
 searchCEP() {

    console.log(this.cepDigitado);

    this.cepService.ceps(this.cepDigitado)
        .subscribe(cep => {
        this.cep = cep; console.log(this.cep); /*this.cepArray.push(this.cep);*/ console.log(this.cepArray);
        },
            error => { alert("Erro") });
}
```

My component.html

```
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let c of cep">
      <td>{{c.cidade}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Response Json

```
{
   "complemento": "de 1907/1908 ao fim",
   "bairro": "Aeroporto",
   "cidade": "Barretos",
   "logradouro": "Rua 26",
   "estado_info": {
      "area_km2": "248.221,996",
      "codigo_ibge": "35",
      "nome": "São Paulo"
   },
  "cep": "14783232",
  "cidade_info": {
      "area_km2": "1566,161",
      "codigo_ibge": "3505500"
   },
   "estado": "SP"
}
```

Comment: [how-to-transpose-a-javascript-object-into-a-key-value-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411566/how-to-transpose-a-javascript-object-into-a-key-value-array)

Answer (score 1):

`*ngFor` directive do work on only iterable object. If you want to loop over all the property of an object, you could use `keyValue` pipe

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of cep | keyValue">
      <td>{{item.key}} {{item.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** it needs Angular 6.1 version (`keyValue` pipe got add in that release)

---

Or if you just wanted to show up just a single property of any object, you can consider putting `cep` result into `ceps` collection like below. Then existing solution would work as expected.

```
ceps: any[] = []
searchCEP() {
    console.log(this.cepDigitado);
    this.cepService.ceps(this.cepDigitado)
      .subscribe(cep => {
        this.ceps = [cep]; console.log(this.cep);
      })
}
```

Comment: Hi, now this error has appeared: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keyValue' could not be found ("
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 offset-md-4">
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="l[ERROR ->]et c of cep | keyValue">
            <td>{{c.key}} {{c.value}}</td>
        </tr>
"):

Comment: make sure you have angular 6.1+

Comment: My version: dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },

Comment: The second solution also did not work, and I would like to display almost all the data

Comment: @Todd7 update to `6.1.7` version of all angular packages, do fire `ng update @angular/core` command if you're using Angular CLI

Comment: Angular 6.1.7 works    <tr *ngFor="let item of cep | keyValue">
      <td>{{item.key}} {{item.value}}</td>
    </tr> ?

Comment: @Todd7 great! accept and upvote answer if it works for you :)