# How to query (find) in field of Object type?

Tags: mongodb, find

I have collection of documents like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5e7638edfe406adbff385784'),
    chat: 109081533,
    user: 109081533,
    data: {
        name: 'Max',
        address: {
            '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7': {
                transfer_orders: {
                    '1584806368': {
                        state: 'new',
                        from: '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7',
                        to: '0x590631dd6f3ef395ca46ad5108f4fb4ab9ef0cd4',
                        amount: '22',
                        data: 'some info'
                    },
                    '1584806512': {
                        state: 'pending',
                        from: '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7',
                        to: '0xFdd8b50f36a3810b7971dd9631f885E2f2Fb400C',
                        amount: '33',
                        data: 'some info'
                    },
                    '1584898932': {
                        state: 'new',
                        from: '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7',
                        to: '0x590631dd6f3ef395ca46ad5108f4fb4ab9ef0cd4',
                        amount: '121',
                        data: 'some info'
                    },
                    '1584924924': {
                        state: 'ok',
                        from: '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7',
                        to: '0xb2aff88b085b4f01ea89b39407c04faa962e153d',
                        amount: '222',
                        data: 'some info'
                    },
                    '1585144560': {
                        state: 'new',
                        from: '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7',
                        to: '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7',
                        amount: '22',
                        data: 'some info'
                    }
                },
                income: {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. How to project inner objects where state =='new' ?
2. How to find documents where inner objects where state =='new' ?

I have tried dot notation like this `find_one({"data.address.0.transfer_orders.0": {state: "new"}})`.  But **address** and **transfer_orders** elements are not arrays. I have found that `find({"data.address": {$type: 3}})`  is work for my collection.  Hence address element is object type. But how to query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For objects with id keys in not an easy task to write a query.

I assume your keys (`0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7`, `1584898932`) aren't part of the db schema, therefore they cannot be indexed

However, for array you can use operators like `$elemMatch` see here: [Query an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)

I suggest you to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411566/how-to-transpose-a-javascript-object-into-a-key-value-array) your maps (objects) to arrays instead

```
transfer_orders: [
  'key': '1584806368',
  'value': {
      state: 'new',
      from: '0x3cd68b454bce1c7be95a3587bfd71d1be9bb85a7',
      to: '0x590631dd6f3ef395ca46ad5108f4fb4ab9ef0cd4',
      amount: '22',
      data: 'some info'
   }
]
```