# How to make array of objects with specific key and value from object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My initial object is:

​`const initObject = {"ITEM1": "Item 1", "ITEM2: "Item 2"}`

How to convert it to:

`​const convertedArray = [{value: "ITEM1", label: "Item 1"}, {value: "ITEM2", label="Item 2"}]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transpose a javascript object into a key/value array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411566/how-to-transpose-a-javascript-object-into-a-key-value-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const convertedArray = Object.keys(initObject).map((x)=> { return {
   value : x,
 label: initObject[x]
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try map through the object keys to create the array using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like the following way:

```js
const initObject = {"ITEM1": "Item 1", "ITEM2": "Item 2"};
const convertedArray = Object.keys(initObject).map(k => ({value: k, label: initObject[k]}));
console.log(convertedArray);
```

Note: You have missed closing`"` in key in `"ITEM2: "Item 2"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a list of key value pairs on which you can loop on and create your array.

```js
const initObject = {"ITEM1": "Item 1", "ITEM2": "Item 2"};
const convertedArray = Object.entries(initObject).map(([key, value]) => ({value: key, label: value}));
console.log(convertedArray);
```