# How to convert an array with one object and multiple keys into an array of multiple objects using those keys and their values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have an array like so with a single object inside:

```
FirstArray = [{
    "category": "None",
    "ARFE": 553.5,
    "BV": 900,
    "RF rfeer": 0,
    .....
}]
```

I want to convert it so that every key-value pair (where the value is a number) in the object is in its own object like the following:

```
NewArray = [{
  name: "ARFE",
  value: 553.05
}, {
  name: "BV",
  value: 900
}, {
  name: "RF rfeer",
  value: 0
}, .....]
```

Here, each key was assigned a new key called **name**, and the value for the original key was assigned a new key called **value**. Those pairs are then put into their own object inside the array.

Note that ***"category": "None" is not its own object in the array since "None" is non-numerical.***

It's also important to note that there could be many key-value pairs, so it's not just limited to the items above (e.g., "ARFE": 553.5, etc.)

What I have so far:

I know you can separate a single object into multiple objects:

```
NewArray = Object.entries(FirstArray).reduce((prev, [og, nw]) => {
    let [name, value] = og.match(/\D+|\d+$/g)
    prev[value] = { ...(prev[value] || {}), [name]: nw }
    return prev;
 }, {})
```

I also know how that you can create a new object with new keys like so:

```
NewArray = Object.assign(
    ...Object.entries(FirstArray).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: name }))
);
```

However, I'm having trouble putting everything together. How would I be able to achieve NewArray from FirstArray?

Comment: There is no JSON involved in this question. Please do not use the tag when discussing plain JavaScript objects. I've removed the tag from your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transpose a javascript object into a key/value array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411566/how-to-transpose-a-javascript-object-into-a-key-value-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close. All you needed to do is specify the name:

```js
const data = {
    "category": "None",
    "ARFE": 553.5,
    "BV": 900,
    "RF rfeer": 0
};

const result = Object
    .entries(data)
    .filter(([_, value]) => typeof value === 'number')
    .map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Also, if you don't want `{ "name": "category", "value": "None" }` to be included in the result, you can just filter it:

```
const result = Object
    .entries(data)
    .filter(([ key ]) => key !== 'category')
    .map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, value }));
```

Comment: That works really well! Though I wrote that any key-value pair where the value is non-numerical (like "category": "None") have to be excluded from the final array. In such a case, would that require a foreach that encompasses all of the const result?

Comment: @naru-magi: No, that can be filtered as well. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries` on array has no sense at all, use it on the object

```js
const FirstArray = [{
  "category": "None",
  "ARFE": 553.5,
  "BV": 900,
  "RF rfeer": 0,
}]

const newObject = Object.entries(FirstArray[0]).reduce((array, [key, value]) => {
  return [...array, {
    name: key,
    value
  }]
}, [])

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: Why are you using `reduce` to build the new array?

Comment: Just by a mistake but it shows what op did wrong more clearly

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` is not the right way to go. Simply use `map`:

```js
Object.entries(FirstArray[0])
    .filter(x => !isNaN(x[1]))    // filter out non-numeric values
    .map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}))
```